# [Simba][AthenaJDBC](100071) An error has been thrown from the AWS Athena client. Unsupported data type in EXPLAIN (TYPE IO)

Tags: amazon-web-services, jdbc, amazon-athena

I am getting below error when i am trying to run a query from Athena. the query is a SELECT and not an EXPLAIN. It gives the error below :

```
[Simba][AthenaJDBC](100071) An error has been thrown from the AWS Athena client. NOT_SUPPORTED: Unsupported data type in EXPLAIN (TYPE IO): date
```

I tried running the query on Athena directly and it works as expected

Comment: Can you share more details on how you are issuing the query from JDBC client?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.